# Difficulty with cnn in keras

Tags: neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, theano-cuda

I'm trying to build a dcnn, but I got this error:

> ValueError: ('The specified size contains a dimension with value <= 0', (-192, 1024))

And really, I don't have idea the reason of this error, here's my code:

The data:

```
c_X = open("C:/Users/PC/Desktop/Notebooks/Isabelle/mfcc_train_I_C_I_C_2.dat", "r")
c_y = open("C:/Users/PC/Desktop/Notebooks/Isabelle/phoneme_train_I_C_I_C_2.dat", "r")
c_X = np.fromfile(c_X, np.dtype('float32'))
c_y = np.fromfile(c_y, np.dtype('int8'))
c_X = c_X.reshape(886887,1120)
c_X = c_X.reshape(c_X.shape[0], 1, 20, 56)
c_y = one_hot(c_y)
#c_y = np.append(c_y, np.zeros((374975,1)), axis=1)
X_3 = apendice(Colere_X, c_X)
y_3 = apendice(Colere_y, c_y)
#print(c_X.shape, c_y.shape)
print(X_3.shape, y_3.shape)
(1123867, 1, 20, 56) (1123867, 38)
```

This is my neural network implementation (the problem is here I think):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), border_mode='valid', activation='relu',input_shape=(1, 20, 56)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), border_mode='valid', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), border_mode='valid', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Train the model
start = time.time()
model_info = model.fit(X_3, y_3, batch_size=100, \
                         epochs=20, verbose=2, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
end = time.time()
```

Here the summary of model:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_21 (Conv2D)           (None, -1, 18, 32)        16160     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_16 (Dropout)         (None, -1, 18, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_22 (Conv2D)           (None, -3, 16, 32)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_11 (MaxPooling (None, -2, 8, 32)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_17 (Dropout)         (None, -2, 8, 32)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_23 (Conv2D)           (None, -4, 6, 32)         9248      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_24 (Conv2D)           (None, -6, 4, 32)         9248      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_12 (MaxPooling (None, -3, 2, 32)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_18 (Dropout)         (None, -3, 2, 32)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_6 (Flatten)          (None, -192)              0         
=================================================================
Total params: 43,904
Trainable params: 43,904
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-589407073ff5> in <module>()
     13 model.add(Flatten())
     14 model.summary()
---> 15 model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
     16 model.add(Dropout(0.5))
     17 model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in add(self, layer)
    467                           output_shapes=[self.outputs[0]._keras_shape])
    468         else:
--> 469             output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
    470             if isinstance(output_tensor, list):
    471                 raise TypeError('All layers in a Sequential model '

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    567                                          '`layer.build(batch_input_shape)`')
    568                 if len(input_shapes) == 1:
--> 569                     self.build(input_shapes[0])
    570                 else:
    571                     self.build(input_shapes)

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py in build(self, input_shape)
    823                                       name='kernel',
    824                                       regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
--> 825                                       constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
    826         if self.use_bias:
    827             self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=(self.units,),

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     85                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
     86                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 87             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     88         wrapper._original_function = func
     89         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py in add_weight(self, name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, trainable, constraint)
    389         if dtype is None:
    390             dtype = K.floatx()
--> 391         weight = K.variable(initializer(shape), dtype=dtype, name=name)
    392         if regularizer is not None:
    393             self.add_loss(regularizer(weight))

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers.py in __call__(self, shape, dtype)
    206             limit = np.sqrt(3. * scale)
    207             return K.random_uniform(shape, -limit, limit,
--> 208                                     dtype=dtype, seed=self.seed)
    209 
    210     def get_config(self):

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\theano_backend.py in random_uniform(shape, minval, maxval, dtype, seed)
   2189         seed = np.random.randint(1, 10e6)
   2190     rng = RandomStreams(seed=seed)
-> 2191     return rng.uniform(shape, low=minval, high=maxval, dtype=dtype)
   2192 
   2193 

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\rng_mrg.py in uniform(self, size, low, high, ndim, dtype, nstreams)
    854                 raise ValueError(
    855                     "The specified size contains a dimension with value <= 0",
--> 856                     size)
    857 
    858         else:

ValueError: ('The specified size contains a dimension with value <= 0', (-192, 256))
```

I will appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you obtain the output of model.summary() and include it in your question?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added the summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem related to the channels ordering in Keras. You probably have set `image_dim_ordering` or `image_data_format parameter` in `~/.keras/keras.json` to either `tf` or `channels_last`, depending on which version of Keras you are using. The problem is that the `input_shape` you provided is in the `th` or `channels first` order, which messes up how the dimensions are interpreted and produces negative dimension sizes.

This would happen if you first used Keras with TensorFlow and then you switched to Theano.

The solution is quite easy, you can either set the corresponding parameter in the `keras.json` config file to `th` or `channels_first` so it matches your file, or you change the `input_shape` of your data to `(20, 56, 1)`. Both solutions should work and you should prefer the native channel ordering of the backend you are using (as it is slightly faster).

Comment: Yes, I have just corrected the error by modifying the image_dim_ordering parameter. Thanks a lot!